# Export multiple local groups members to one text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is there a way to Export the the members of certain local groups to a single txt file? Currently I have been doing it as separately for each group remotely using psexec. Here is the code I use:

```
psexec \\PCName net localgroup "Group1" >C:\TEMP\Group1.txt
psexec \\ PCName net localgroup "Group2" >C:\TEMP\Group2.txt
psexec \\ PCName net localgroup "Group3" >C:\TEMP\Group3.txt
psexec \\ PCName net localgroup "Group4" >C:\TEMP\Group4.txt
```

pause

Also is there a way to add the PC name and date the the same file?

Answer (score 0):

```
(for %L in ("Group1" "Group2" "Group3" "Group4") do (echo Report for PCName %~L on %date %time%&psexec \\PCName net localgroup "%~L")) >C:\TEMP\report.txt
```

should accomplish that task - as a command-line instruction. Replace each `%~L` with `%%~L` to use as a batch file line.

The outer parentheses gather all output to the file nominated. Generally, `>` would create a new file, `>>` append to any existing file.

The loop assigns each quoted name (including the quotes) to `%L` in turn. The `report for...` line with the date, time and groupname is then directed to the file, followed by the results of the `psexec` command. `%~L` removes the quotes from `%L`.

You don't say how you are supplying `PCName`, so I'll not comment on that.

Comment: I tried both suggestions and both worked great, I submitted the output to my QA person to let them decide which report they like the best .

Comment: I tried both suggestions and both worked great, I submitted the output to my QA person to let them decide which report they like the best .

Thank you Joe and Magoo!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
ECHO Date: %DATE% on %TIME% > "C:\TEMP\Groups.txt"
ECHO PC: PCName >> "C:\TEMP\Groups.txt"
ECHO. >> "C:\TEMP\Groups.txt"

ECHO Group 1: >> "C:\TEMP\Groups.txt"
psexec \\PCName net localgroup "Group1" >> "C:\TEMP\Groups.txt"
ECHO Group 2: >> "C:\TEMP\Groups.txt"
psexec \\PCName net localgroup "Group2" >> "C:\TEMP\Groups.txt"
ECHO Group 3: >> "C:\TEMP\Groups.txt"
psexec \\PCName net localgroup "Group3" >> "C:\TEMP\Groups.txt"
ECHO Group 4: >> "C:\TEMP\Groups.txt"
psexec \\PCName net localgroup "Group4" >> "C:\TEMP\Groups.txt"
```

A single arrow (`>`) will overwrite any existing output file, two arrows (`>>`) will append, or add to the end of any existing output file.

This script will echo the date, the name of the target computer, and all specified groups to the target file.